# Understaning Django's template automatic search/file system

Tags: templates, django

From the tutorial online https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/#customizing-your-project-s-templates it states to place user templates into a directory like so:

```
/project/app/templates/app/example.html
```

But when the automatic template loader searches it looks in:

```
/project/app/templates/
```

Likewise when you try to load a default template that is located at:

```
/Python27/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html
```

It will search in:

```
/Python27/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/
```

Am I missing something here? I have not defined any TEMPLATE_DIRS because I want the default system to operate like the tutorial says.

### UPDATE/SOLUTION:

The reason I was confused is that you put templates that are native to the app in

```
/project/app/templates
```

and then put non-native templates in

```
/project/app/templates/non-native_app-name
```

And also when using `{% extends "template.html" %}` you must place app name before template like so `{% extends "app-name/template.html" %}`

Correct me if I am wrong here... Thanks for the help

Comment: what django version are you using? if the latest version then you're following the wrong tutorial

Answer (score 0):

If you have `django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader` in your `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` settings, this actually should be in your settings by default:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

Then, django will search through `templates` directory in each of your apps, quote from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader):

> Loads templates from Django apps on the filesystem. For each app in
>   INSTALLED_APPS, the loader looks for a templates subdirectory. If the
>   directory exists, Django looks for templates in there.
>
> This means you can store templates with your individual apps. This
>   also makes it easy to distribute Django apps with default templates.

Answer (score 0):

if u read django's source, you can find code in django.template.loaders.py .

```
def find_template(name, dirs=None):
  # Calculate template_source_loaders the first time the function is executed
  # because putting this logic in the module-level namespace may cause
  # circular import errors. See Django ticket #1292.
  global template_source_loaders
  if template_source_loaders is None:
      loaders = []
      for loader_name in settings.TEMPLATE_LOADERS:
          loader = find_template_loader(loader_name)
          if loader is not None:
              loaders.append(loader)
      template_source_loaders = tuple(loaders)
  for loader in template_source_loaders:
      try:
          source, display_name = loader(name, dirs)
          return (source, make_origin(display_name, loader, name, dirs))
      except TemplateDoesNotExist:
          pass
  raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
```